# Path and Symbols eclipse MPI for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, mpi, openmpi

I've installed OpenMPI and all the tools for eclipse to work with MPI. There's only a little problem. When I create a project to work with **MPI-C++** I always have to include the path to the project "Symbols and Paths" configuration so statements like `MPI::Init(argc, argv);`are recognized by eclipse.

Is there a way to make **all** the projects have the `include` path set to the proper directory of MPI? This only happens with C++ 'cause when I try with C eclipse recognizes all the MPI functions.

[image]

Comment: On a completely side note - the MPI C++ bindings were deprecated some time ago in MPI-2.2 and were completely removed from MPI-3.0. The MPI Forum advises its users to either use the C bindings or to resort to a 3rd party C++ interface (e.g. `Boost.MPI`, which unfortunately does not cover lots of present MPI functionality).

Comment: Thanks, I mean that's a little off topic but it's nice to know it. So now in MPI-3.0 there are only C-like functions for either C or C++ ? Do you have a link to that info?

Comment: In MPI-3.0 there are only the C functions that have existed since the down of MPI (with some additions and removal of deprecated ones). As usual the link is [MPI Standard Documents](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/docs.html). I would recommend the "alternate formatting" version which uses red colour to signify the added/removed parts.

Comment: @HristoIliev for an explanation of the motivation and consequences of the removal of C++ bindings I would refer also to [this blog post/link to cisco.com/](http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/the-mpi-c-bindings-are-gone-what-does-it-mean-to-you/) by Jeff Squires and some of the previous posts linked there. May be it's time to have a SO post on it.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov, my (hopefully wrong) impression is that almost nobody uses the search functionality of SO and such post would quickly sink in oblivion.

Comment: Anyone? Any idea on how to fix this?